# Is there a Java equivalent to AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property) from C#

Tags: java, c#

I am migrating a C# solution to Java and being a beginner in Java I am having difficulties migrating the below piece of code :
in C#:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DefaultField: Attribute
{
    public DefaultField()
    {
        this.HasDefaultValue = false;
    }

    public DefaultField(object defaultValue)
    {
        this.DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.HasDefaultValue = true;
    }

    internal bool HasDefaultValue;
    internal object DefaultValue;
}
```

with the below usage as example:

```
[DefaultField(1.0)]
public double WindowSize { get; set; }

[DefaultField("Summary")]
public string WindowTitle { get; set; }
```

I tried looking at interface and annotations but the only thing I was able to do was to create an interface for a specific Object e.g. Double, Int, String without even being able to check if the default value had been set

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface DefaultField{
    double value();
}
```

with the below usage:

```
@DefaultField(0.0)
public double val;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited: My original answer was not correct, thus: edited)

Problem with annotations is that they accept only constants values, which are: primitives, String and enums.

Therefore the best solution seems to be using a String that contains serialized value and then during annotation processing parse it differently depending on the actual type of the field.

This means that for each type `T` you'll have to have a method `Function<String,T>`. For primitive types you can directly use factory methods from those types:

- bool:  `Boolean::parseBoolean`
- int: `Integer::parseInt`
- float: `Float::parseFloat`
- etc

If you want to handle enum, then you can use `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType,String name)`. For other types that are in jdk and they have some sort of factory method, you can still use it, i.e.`LocalDateTime::parse)`.

However, if you want to be able to provide default value to any type, then you'll need to decide how you want to represent its value when it's serialized into String. You could use something generic like JSON and then use Gson library to parse it.

====================== INCORRECT (OLD) ANSWER BELOW =================

If you want to be able to pass various types of values i.e. `@DefaultField(0.1)` or `@DefaultField("string")` then you'd have to declare `value()` as of type `Object`.

It's the rest of the code that you implement for processing annotation that will have to verify if that matches type of the field (I assume that you'll just want to set to this value in case it's not initialized other way).

Comment: Thank you Mirek but when I tried to declare value() as an Object I get the below error message : "Invalid type Object for annotation member".

Comment: My bad, I have completely missed that fact. I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you Mirek this is very clear and answers my question.